# Can I incorporate a small fraction of a song into my iOS game?

Tags: music, copyright

I was wondering if I can use a small portion of a song without running into any copyright issues. I would give full credit to the artist as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need permission from the copyright holder.

Without explicit permission, you would be committing a copyright violation, even when you just use a small part of a song. Giving credit never makes an otherwise illegal copyright violation legal.

And you likely will get sued, because the music industry is constantly looking for reasons to sue people for the smallest infraction of the intellectual property they bought from the artists.

Comment: some artists are more than happy for you to use their music if you attribute

Comment: @Yakyb That is true, but most would prefer that you asked for permission before just using their music. At least they will understand why they getting feedback about it instead of being blind-sided.

Comment: agreed but that is a hypothetical, it is a bit strong to say 'no you can not' when in fact you can, but it varies wildly on the artist and particular song / track.

Comment: @Yakyb I edited my answer to add the possibility to get the copyright holders permission (which might no longer be the artist).

Answer (score 1):

depends on the license the song is available under, Creative Commons license has many guises some of which allow for usage so long as you nominate artist.

the various licenses are explained quite well at 'open game art'

http://opengameart.org/content/faq